# What does it mean to generate all cyclic subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

In the case of $\Bbb Z_8$ with the operation of addition

<0> = {0},

<2> = <6> = {0, 2, 4, 6},

<4> = {0, 4},

<1> = <3> = <5> = <7> = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}.

are cyclic subgroups the same as subgroups that are cyclic?

so in this case, the cyclic subgroup is {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, generated by <1> = <3> = <5> = <7>

or all the above are cyclic subgroups? So when a question asks for generate cyclic subgroups, it just wants me to generate all the groups for each element in the set $\Bbb Z_8$?

Comment: For every group $G$, and every $g\in G$, $\langle g\rangle$ is the (cyclic) subgroup generated by $g$, which you can always build up.

Comment: A cyclic group is by definition one which can be generated by one element only, namely all of whose elements are powers (in multiplicative groups, "multiples" in additive groups) of one single element. A cyclic group can have more than one generator, as your own example shows.

Comment: Since subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic, all subgroups of $\Bbb Z/8$ are cyclic. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718041/list-all-subgroups-of-mathbb-z-6-and-mathbb-z-8?rq=1) for your homework. And yes, cyclic subgroups are the same as subgroups that are cyclic. This is just a language issue.